# A list of Shulchan Aruch Halachot that repeat themselves?

Tags: halacha, sexuality, shulchan-aruch, famine

I'm researching the prohibition for couples to have relations at a time of famine, which is brought by the Shulchan Aruch in Orach Chaim 240:12, Orach Chaim 574:4 and Even Ha'ezer 25:6. While many of the rulings found in Orach Chaim 240 are repeated (or modified) in Even Ha'ezer 25, this struck me as somewhat bizarre that the same halacha was repeated three times in Shulchan Aruch, although it makes sense to bring this halacha in each place.

I was wondering if there is a listing of halachot that appear multiple times in Shulchan Aruch, so that I could examine them to see if there is a particular significance/emphasis to those halachot. Alternatively, if anyone is aware of later sources that address repetition in Shulchan Aruch, that would be useful as well.

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome back! Here's an apparent example in the Rema, only one se'if apart: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/100407/why-did-r-moses-isserles-state-the-same-law-twice-in-a-row

Comment: @Alex thanks! Not sure how long I'll be back for, but good to be back for this amount of time.

Comment: There are also the times he specifically doesn't repeat himself like YD 121:3

Comment: Your phrasing was misleading, like if it was about the reason for repetitions. If you ask for a list, please state that you ask for a list.

Comment: It is about the reason for repetitions. But if you have a list, that would enable me to personally examine cases and see what I can come up with. @alberko Although I'm fine with your edit.

Comment: If you ask why, I have a couple of thoughts: the book we're talking about (just like all the previous) wasn't a single manuscript. It was polished over centuries by scholars, redactors, and publishers. Maybe it is worth comparing earlier versions. Also, IMHO Halachic writing is imaginative, not scientific, so if the same idea comes to mind over and over, it can be recorded again.